# Average rate only between different values SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find out the average work rate.

The data I using looks like this:

```
dtimecre                |rem_lines
2017-08-17 12:00:03.907 |17879
2017-08-17 11:00:03.630 |20520
2017-08-17 10:03:08.840 |25330
2017-08-17 09:00:03.830 |30613
2017-08-17 08:01:04.473 |34260
2017-08-17 07:00:12.450 |41459
2017-08-17 06:00:07.983 |45898
2017-08-17 05:00:28.587 |45898
2017-08-17 04:00:15.600 |45898
2017-08-17 03:00:04.210 |45898
2017-08-17 02:00:09.057 |45898
2017-08-17 01:00:04.020 |45898
2017-08-17 00:02:07.860 |49666
2017-08-16 23:00:05.723 |56688
2017-08-16 22:00:06.257 |64248
```

So we can see they started working at 6:00 o'clock, I want to just get the average difference across those values and to ignore everything below. So the value I'm looking for is. 4,669

I'm thinking I can can create a temporary using a while loop to list the differences? and to jump out when my difference = 0 then average the total in the temp table? or is it better to try and use time as my reference point and so I know at the 12:00 hours I need to find the average between 7 and 12.

Comment: are the rem_lines always increasing per each line like that? Or is that just in your sample

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. "So we can see they started working at 7:00"? How do we see this? There's a lot of assumptions you have on your end that you haven't described here. Please explain more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I'm sorry I posted it in the wrong sorting order. The time is going up.

Comment: We can see they started working at 7:00 because thats when the values start moving down again.

Comment: Can we assume that we should check for "start times" at the start of a new day?  i.e. we go through rows until we find it starting at the beginning of the day.  Meaning in your data we could disregard the 22:00:06 row (the last row).  Or should checking for "start time" only occur if there is the same rem_lines two or three (more?) times in a  row?

Comment: Is it more correct to say that the start time was 06:00?  Or did rem-lines magically reduce at 07:00 with no work required?

Comment: Element, yes we would ignore the last row since it was the previous day.   And Brett, you're correct they actually started working at 6:00. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using window functions available in SQL Server 2012 in a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to determine the previous value for `rem_lines` using [**`lag()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx), get the difference between those values, and determine the start of a new work day based on some period of idleness for each day:

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , idle_count = count(case when change = 0 then 1 end) 
        over (partition by convert(date,dtimecre) order by dtimecre asc)
  from (
    select *
      , prev_rem_lines = lag(rem_lines) over (order by dtimecre desc)
      , change = rem_lines-lag(rem_lines) over (order by dtimecre desc)
    from t
  ) s
)
select 
    dcre = convert(date,dtimecre)
  , avg_lines = avg(change)
from cte
where idle_count > 0
  and change > 0
group by convert(date,dtimecre)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MNBP59565

returns:

```
+------------+-----------+
|    dcre    | avg_lines |
+------------+-----------+
| 2017-08-17 |      4669 |
+------------+-----------+
```

---

Showing some more aggregations by changing the final query:

```
select 
    dcre = convert(date,dtimecre)
  , idle_count
  , start_dtimecre = min(dtimecre)
  , end_dtimecre   = max(dtimecre)
  , avg_lines      = avg(change)
  , max_rem_lines  = max(rem_lines)
  , min_rem_lines  = min(prev_rem_lines)
from cte
where change > 0
group by convert(date,dtimecre), idle_count
order by start_dtimecre desc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SPQ44073

returns:

```
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|    dcre    | idle_count |   start_dtimecre    |    end_dtimecre     | avg_lines | max_rem_lines | min_rem_lines |
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| 2017-08-17 |          5 | 2017-08-17 06:00:07 | 2017-08-17 11:00:03 |      4669 |         45898 |         17879 |
| 2017-08-17 |          0 | 2017-08-17 00:02:07 | 2017-08-17 00:02:07 |      3768 |         49666 |         45898 |
| 2017-08-16 |          0 | 2017-08-16 22:00:06 | 2017-08-16 23:00:05 |      7291 |         64248 |         49666 |
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: alright I'm impressed.  I didn't even know about the lag function so thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @ElementZero `lag()` (and its companion `lead()`) are very useful analytic window functions. I'm sure you will find plenty of uses for them!

Comment: I can see.  I'll have to read up on them.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I had no idea about the lead and lag functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to find the row with the start time.  I'm unsure what to do next though because you say you want an `AVG` but didn't specify an `AVG` of what

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @temp table
(
    dtimecre datetime,
    rem_lines int
)

INSERT INTO @temp
select '2017-08-17 12:00:03.907', '17879' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 11:00:03.630', '20520' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 10:03:08.840', '25330' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 09:00:03.830', '30613' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 08:01:04.473', '34260' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 07:00:12.450', '41459' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 06:00:07.983', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 05:00:28.587', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 04:00:15.600', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 03:00:04.210', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 02:00:09.057', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 01:00:04.020', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 00:02:07.860', '49666' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-16 23:00:05.723', '56688' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-16 22:00:06.257', '64248'

declare @BeforeWork datetime 

select @BeforeWork = max(dtimecre) 
from @temp
where rem_lines = ( select rem_lines
                    from @temp
                    group by rem_lines
                    having count(rem_lines) > 1
                  )

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rem_lines DESC) AS RowNo, rem_lines, dtimecre 
    FROM @temp
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT t1.rem_lines, t1.dtimecre, COALESCE(t1.rem_lines - t2.rem_lines,0) AS diff
    FROM CTE t1
        LEFT JOIN CTE t2 ON t1.RowNo = t2.RowNo + 1
    where t1.dtimecre > @BeforeWork
)
select @BeforeWork as WorkStartTime, ABS(AVG(diff)) as TotalAvg from CTE2
```

### Result

```
WorkStartTime  | TotalAvg
---------------+---------
08/17/2017     | 4669
```

TEST: http://rextester.com/ICMP46339

However as @Brett saw they start at 6, not 7 so in that case the number should (?) be 4541

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rem_lines DESC) AS RowNo, rem_lines, dtimecre 
    FROM @temp
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT t1.rem_lines, t1.dtimecre, COALESCE(t1.rem_lines - t2.rem_lines,0) AS diff
    FROM CTE t1
        LEFT JOIN CTE t2 ON t1.RowNo = t2.RowNo + 1
    where t1.dtimecre >= @BeforeWork
)
select @BeforeWork as WorkStartTime, ABS(AVG(diff)) as TotalAvg from CTE2
```

TEST: http://rextester.com/COOFK31760

Comment: Thank you, The average I'm looking for is the difference between rem_lines

Comment: Charles - Do you mean you want to know how many lines have be "done" between each record?  Or that you want the average lines "done" from 07:00 to 12:00?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find the amount of lines done between each record. Then get the average of the amount of  total lines done.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [Element Zero] - I've just pulled some stats at the end to get the average (which comes out at 4669).

```
-- Setup table
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @temp table
(
    dtimecre datetime,
    rem_lines int
)

INSERT INTO @temp
select '2017-08-17 12:00:03.907', '17879' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 11:00:03.630', '20520' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 10:03:08.840', '25330' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 09:00:03.830', '30613' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 08:01:04.473', '34260' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 07:00:12.450', '41459' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 06:00:07.983', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 05:00:28.587', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 04:00:15.600', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 03:00:04.210', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 02:00:09.057', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 01:00:04.020', '45898' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-17 00:02:07.860', '49666' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-16 23:00:05.723', '56688' UNION ALL
select '2017-08-16 22:00:06.257', '64248'

-- Actual answer
declare @BeforeWork datetime 


select @BeforeWork = max(dtimecre) 
from @temp
where rem_lines = ( select rem_lines
                    from @temp
                    group by rem_lines
                    having count(rem_lines) > 1
                  )

declare @startingLines int
declare @endingLines int
declare @countOfPeriods int

select @startingLines = rem_lines from @temp where dtimecre = @BeforeWork order by dtimecre ASC
select @endingLines = min(rem_lines) from @temp
select @countOfPeriods = count(*) from @temp where dtimecre > @BeforeWork

select Average = (@startingLines-@endingLines) / @countOfPeriods
```